# Guice override some bindings in an existing injector

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have an `Injector` instance `a`, and I'd like to create another `Injector b` which does the same as `a`, except for two bindings, which get overridden by the `Module` I provide. Is this possible?

I know about `Modules.override`, but that does not take an `Injector` as argument. If it was possible to convert an `Injector` to a `Module`, that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way of thinking about this would be through [child injectors](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#createChildInjector%28com.google.inject.Module...%29), but that is [explicitly disallowed as a design decision](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-guice/naqT-fOrOTw):

> The reason overriding a binding in a child injector isn't supported is because it can lead a developer towards writing code that can work in either a parent & child injector, but have different behavior in each.  This can lead to very surprising scenarios, because of just-in-time (JIT) bindings and the way they interact with parent/child injectors.

At this point, I would probably think about restructuring your application to avoid requiring these complicated bindings, but if you want to go further, you can probably use [Injector.getBindings()](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getBindings%28%29) or [Injector.getAllBindings()](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getAllBindings%28%29) (note the difference!) and stitch them back into a module using the [Elements SPI](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InspectingModules). After all, `Binding<?>` extends `Element`, and [Elements.getModule(...)](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/Elements.html#getModule%28java.lang.Iterable%3C?%20extends%20com.google.inject.spi.Element%3E%29) will create a Module from your Elements. I haven't checked that it works, but that's probably your best lead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will give it a try.  One comment: I don't think that the OP was using "complicated bindings".  What he was describing was exactly what one would do in a unit test.  Unit testing is most efficient when you can selectively override parts of your system.  That is, you would want default bindings in place, and an easy mechanism to override one or two at runtime.  That is standard TDD.  I am new to Guice and maybe I am missing something.  However I see many developers asking similar questions and I am disappointed that Guice does not make this simple functionality available.

Comment: @EJK `Modules.override` is specifically and exactly the best way to override for unit testing, should you need to inject in a unit test, and my complicated answer was in response to the general nature of the question and the specific avoidance of `Modules.override`. Overriding an Injector instead of a Module is a bit like making an omelette out of meringue instead of eggs—unprocessed input gives better results.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I see your point now.  I do wish the Guice / RoboGuice docs were a bit more clear on this.  There seems to be an awful lot of confusion on this one topic.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; however, I tried that and ran into a lot of problems with the approach. As soon as your bindings are nontrivial, `Injector.getBindings()` will start giving you things like `ExposedBinding` which cannot be passed to `Elements.getModule()`. I tried to work around that, but had to abandon the idea.